# R: Remove duplicated value conditionally between row keeping the one with less NA

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I wonder a way to remove duplicated values in a table in R. The problem is that I'm having duplicated rows with NA and some not. I want to *preferably* keep only the row that contains 1) no NA or 2) the less number of NA possible. Here is a sample data frame:

```
mat.test=matrix(c(NA,NA,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,3,1,2,2,2,NA,2,3,1,2,4),byrow = T, 6,3)
colnames(mat.test)=c("MBL","MBW","MBD")
df=as.data.frame(mat.test)
df$BAND=c("JP3540","JP3540","JP3540","JP1500","JP2500","JP2500")
df$Date=c("2012-07-23","2012-07-22","2012-07-24","2011-09-03","2011-09-01","2011-09-02")
df

#MBL MBW MBD   BAND       Date
#1  NA  NA   2 JP3540 2012-07-23
#2  NA  NA  NA JP3540 2012-07-22
#3  NA   3   1 JP3540 2012-07-24
#4   2   2   2 JP1500 2011-09-03
#5  NA   2   3 JP2500 2011-09-01
#6   1   2   4 JP2500 2011-09-02
```

I want to sort my data by date because I want to keep the first duplicated value preferably:

```
 z <- df[order(df$Date, decreasing=F),]
```

I know that for a dataset of this size, I could delete them by hand. But I want to make it automatic. Here is the final output that I want.

```
#  MBL MBW MBD   BAND       Date
#6   1   2   4 JP2500 2011-09-02
#4   2   2   2 JP1500 2011-09-03
#3  NA   3   1 JP3540 2012-07-24
```

Hope you can help me! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We `split` the dataset by the 'BAND' to create a `list` of datasets, get the position of the maximum non-NA elements of the first three columns, subset the dataset and `rbind` it.

```
res <- do.call(rbind,lapply(split(df, df$BAND), 
        function(x) x[which.max(rowSums(!is.na(x[1:3]))),]))
row.names(res) <- NULL
res
#  MBL MBW MBD   BAND       Date
#1   2   2   2 JP1500 2011-09-03
#2   1   2   4 JP2500 2011-09-02
#3  NA   3   1 JP3540 2012-07-24
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `na.omit(your data frame)`